# Automatically add all values on new lines together and show them in a entry field

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, addition

I was working on an app in Tkinter and I needed it to automatically add all float values that are separated by new lines (\n) in a text input field and display the result of all the floats added together in another entry field. I have attached an image of the program.
[Image of the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aum10.png)

Here is the code I have so far.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("BFCalc")
window.geometry("500x875")
E1Val = StringVar()
E1_value = StringVar()
E2_value = StringVar()
E3_value = StringVar()

def CalculateNum():
    LengthVal = float(E1_value.get())
    WidthVal = float(E2_value.get())
    ThicknessVal = float(E3_value.get())

    FinalCalc = LengthVal * WidthVal * ThicknessVal / 144
    FinalCalc = round(FinalCalc,2)

    E4.delete(0,"end")
    E4.insert(END,FinalCalc)
    T1.insert(END,f'{FinalCalc}\n')

def ClearVal():
    E1.delete(0,"end")
    E2.delete(0,"end")
    E3.delete(0,"end")
    E4.delete(0,"end")
    E3.insert(0,'1')

L1 = Label(text="Board Foot Calculator",font='Helvetica 20 bold underline')
L1.pack()

L2 = Label(text="Input",font='Helvetica 16 bold underline')
L2.pack()

L3 = Label(text="Length",font='Helvetica 14 bold italic')
L3.pack()

E1 = Entry(window,font='Goudy 14 bold',textvariable=E1_value)
E1.pack()

L4 = Label(text="Width",font='Helvetica 14 bold italic')
L4.pack()

E2 = Entry(window,font='Goudy 14 bold',textvariable=E2_value)
E2.pack()

L5 = Label(text="Thickness",font='Helvetica 14 bold italic')
L5.pack()

E3 = Entry(window,font='Goudy 14 bold',textvariable=E3_value)
E3.insert(0,'1')
E3.pack()

B1 = Button(window,text="Calculate",font='Helvetica 14 bold',height=2,width=15,command=CalculateNum)
B1.pack(pady=40)

L6 = Label(text="Board Feet",font='Helvetica 16 bold italic')
L6.pack()

E4 = Entry(window,font='Goudy 14 bold')
E4.pack()

B2 = Button(window,text="Clear",font='Helvetica 14 bold',height=2,width=10,command=ClearVal)
B2.pack(pady=40)

L7 = Label(text="",font='Goudy 12')
L7.pack()

T1 = Text(window,width=10,height=40,font='Goudy 12')
T1.place(x=400,y=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Was there any particular problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: Well, I tried using a for loop, but I wasn't quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Hi @LucioRandy and welcome to stackoverflow, it's usually nicer to share your code and (specially share the part that doesn't work properly) and people can be more helpful to you

Comment: I have attached the code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the numbers to a list (if it is just adding and taking away). Then create a function that adds all the numbers in the list together

e.g.

```py
answers = []

def CalculateNum():
    LengthVal = float(E1_value.get())
    WidthVal = float(E2_value.get())
    ThicknessVal = float(E3_value.get())

    FinalCalc = LengthVal * WidthVal * ThicknessVal / 144
    FinalCalc = round(FinalCalc,2)
    answers.append(FinalCalc)

    E4.delete(0,"end")
    E4.insert(END,FinalCalc)
    T1.insert(END,f'{FinalCalc}\n')
    Total() #Goes to add up the total

def Total():
    tot = 0 # The total number
    for num in answers: 
        tot += num # Adds all the numbers in the list to the total
    #print(tot)
    #Then insert the number where you want it to go
```

Comment: Would this be using a Python list, or a Tkinter text widget, because I would like to use a Tkinter text widget.

Comment: This would be using a Python list. You could append it to a list as well as to the tkinter text widget. If you could possibly show your code, that could help

Comment: Alright! I have added the code to the question above.

Comment: I've updated the code to fit with your code. I've tested it and it should work

Comment: Yes! This code works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One possible pythonic one liner:

```
total = sum(map(float, text_field.split())
```